# Github directory structure for a project containing Nodejs lambdas and AWS S3 configs

Tags: node.js, github, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am working on a AWS S3 & lambda project and would like to keep my Nodejs lambda functions together with bucket policy, iam policy etc in a Github repository.

Shall I keep a `src` folder and then have perhaps a `lambdas` subfolder to store all functions (I might have more than one) or since I am considering to use NodeJs, can I simply have a structure like this:

https://github.com/nytlabs/github-s3-deploy

In which my README.md file contains info about my lambda IAM role for execution together with bucket policy etc? I am still inclined to have configs in a resource folder, though. Are there any best practices to do so? Is my structure anyway going to be informed by the programming language I will be using for my lambda? What happens if you have a mix of languages in which you code your functions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worry about exposing sensitive data, you may consider to keep all data in Lambda Environment variable. So in your nodejs project you can easily read vale using `process.env.A`

[image]

You can read more on this URL 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html